# ethernet interface of Kubernetes Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am a newbie in Kubernetes arena. I was reading abt the Kubernetes networking and understood that as soon as a POD is created, it is assigned an IP . But POD is a logical entity which is a collection of containers. Does POD have any ethernet interface to which this IP is assigned ? Can you please provide some detailed info on this ?

Comment: Every pod equips with a special container for sharing ethernet interface.

Comment: @Rajeev Containers in the same Kubernetes Pod live in the same *network namespace* (among other stuff they share). Studying how network namespaces work should answer your question.

Comment: @ccshih is there any cmd to view and explore that special container ? Also, who creates this special container ? is the scheduler schedules the pods in the nods and then docker creates this special container ? is there any role of clustering networking like weave or flannel in this ?

Comment: @RajeevGhosh You can find these containers using `docker ps -a | grep pause`. When a node (kubelet, more precisely) initiates a pod, it not only creates application containers but also this special container. Moreover, it mounts this special container's network namespace onto application containers. That's why they share the same network interface.

Answer (score 0):

As you understood already that POD is just a logical entity, there is no ethernet interface attached to it. The containers launched inside the (logical) pod is mapped to same network with the docker's `--net` option. Some explanation about docker mapping to same network here: [docker-containers-same-internal-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376365/how-to-create-docker-containers-with-the-same-internal-ip-address)